# Remove div + its index in Firebase database and add new div in the container

Tags: jquery, firebase

I'm new to Firebase and I started to work on a chat room, it works as intended apart from one thing. I want to have a cap on the number of messages to be displayed, I've done this with limit(13). The next part is what I don't quite understand how to do.. When the cap is at 13, I want to remove the first message (`#messagesDiv div:nth-child(1)`) from the chat and also remove it from my Firebase database. Also, when I remove the first message, I want to add the new message at the same time at the bottom of the list. I've tried looking at the Firebase documentation but I'm not finding anything close to what I want to achieve. If the question is vague let me know how I can make it more clear. Help is appreciated.

```
dataAddQuery = myDataRef.startAt().limit(13); //<-- Maximum messages displayed

dataAddQuery.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var message = snapshot.val();
    displayChatMessage(message.name, message.text);
});

dataRemoveQuery = myDataRef.endAt().limit(1); //<-- Does this remove the 1st message?

dataRemoveQuery.on('child_removed', function(snapshot) {
    var message = snapshot.val();
    removeChatMessage(message.name, message.text);
    //Tried to call displayChatMessage here but that didn't work the way I wanted
});

$('#messageInput').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var name = $('#nameInput').val();
        var text = $('#messageInput').val();
        myDataRef.push({name: name, text: text});
        $('#messageInput').val('');
    }
});

function displayChatMessage(name, text) {

    $('<div/>').text(text).prepend($('<b/>').text(name+': ')).appendTo($('#messagesDiv'));
};

function removeChatMessage(name, text) {

    $('#messagesDiv div:nth-child(1)').remove();
}
```

Comment: I'm not completely clear on your use-case. Do you want to limit the view to only display 13 messages? Or do you want to limit Firebase to only contain 13 messages?

Comment: both if possible, because I don't want to store old messages.

Comment: Then I would go without a query. Simply retrieve all of them and remove the oldest child(ren) from Firebase if you have more than 13. I'll write up a quick sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to limit both the view and the data to 13 items, I'd only focus on the data. If you can limit the number of children to 13, you can simply display all of them.

I wrote up [a quick jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/wagata/edit):

```
var childnames = [];
ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  // display child
  childnames.push(snapshot.name());
  if (childnames.length > 13) {
    ref.child(childnames[0]).remove();
    childnames = childnames.slice(1);
  }
});
ref.on('child_removed', function(snapshot) {
  list.removeChild(document.getElementById(snapshot.name()));
});
```

I simply identify the children's elements in HTML by setting their `id` to the `name` of the Firebase ref.

I hope the flow is clear, if not check the bin and let me know.

Comment: Really clever solution.. I went with an overflow: auto; to display more than 13 but this solution I will definitely use in my other project. Thanks!